# How do I use regex to find an abnormal date in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently cleaning a dataset with a column of strings containing delimiters of various types like `#` `?` `|` `;` `/`

I'm looking to capture any date in the string that is not of the format `2022-09-19T07:20:00` (The years in my dataset are usually of the format 20XX, like 2022 or 2023)

How do I do capture these outliers without writing a complex regex?

Here's an example of an outlier `+5002522-03-04T01:03:00`

Here's a sample string:

`0/0/Just/Some/2022-07-06T17:05:00/2022-07-06T19:25:00/Sample/6780/Data/in///my_Dataset`

Please Advise.

Comment: What output do you expect from the sample strings?

Comment: The regex should capture and output the outlier like this `+5002522-03-04T01:03:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match the outliers based on the example provided

`[\/#?:|][^\/#?:|]+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[\/#?:|]`

https://regex101.com/r/6R4YMQ/1

We set the normal timestamp with `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`

We want the string to be between the delimiters `[\/#?:|]`

So if there are any non-delimiter characters before the timestamp `[^\/#?:|]+` it's a match.

Comment: Will it work if there's multiple dates in the same string?

Comment: You mean will it match all bad ones or find the malformed?

Comment: Nevermind I figured that one out lol. Your answer works nice and clean I caught the outleir!